# Byte-compilation of a multi-file package: "the function is not known to be defined"

Tags: byte-compilation, cask

Imagine that I have the following files in my (ridiculous) package:

File `test1.el`:

```
;;; test1.el ---                                   

;;; Code:

(defvar test-var1)

(defun test-fun1 (test)
  nil)

(require 'test2 "./test2.el)

(provide 'test1)
;;; test1.el ends here
```

File `test2.el`:

```
;;; test2.el ---  

;;; Code:

(defun test-fun2 ()
  (let ((test test-var1))
    (test-fun1 test)))

(provide 'test2)
;;; test2.el ends here
```

If then I run:

```
emacs -batch -f batch-byte-compile *.el
```

I get the following result:

```
Compiling .../test1.el...
Wrote .../test1.elc
Compiling .../test2.el...

In test-fun2:
test2.el:9:15:Warning: reference to free variable `test-var1'

In end of data:
test2.el:14:1:Warning: the function `test-fun1' is not known to be defined.
Wrote .../test2.elc
```

I understand why these warnings appear, and I understand that they are only warnings. However, it would be easy to miss a typo in a function name by dismissing all warnings of this kind.

I somehow thought that adding a `(require 'test2)` line in `test2.el` should fix it. However, in this case I get:

```
Compiling .../test1.el...

In toplevel form:
test1.el:10:1:Error: Recursive `require' for feature `test2'
Compiling .../test2.el...

In toplevel form:
test2.el:5:1:Error: Recursive `require' for feature `test1'
```

This is cryptic, because I thought that the point of `require` was precisely to avoid recursive loading. I assume that `require` is behaving like `load` during compilation time.

What is a good (and safe) way to get rid of these warnings?

The manual gives a work-around (I post it as a better-than-nothing answer below), but ultimately, I'd like the solution to be rather automatic (not requiring me to list all functions and variables that I will need in every file).

The ideal solution would be built-in in emacs or provided with Cask. If it doesn't exist, I will take what is available of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### About require

`require` is not meant to avoid recusive loading, it is meant to avoid *repetitive* loading. So no, it does not solve you problem here.

#### About the problem

The right way to approach this (in my opinion) would be to avoid the
mutual dependency.

The `test1` file in your example has no reason to require `test2`.
Even if that's not true for your actual package, maybe you can
redesign how you're delegating code between the files. It is *in
general* possible to avoid mutual dependency between your files.

#### Work arounds

1. If the mutual dependency cannot be avoided, the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Compiler-Errors.html#Compiler-Errors)
   mentions a solution. You'll have to add lines like the following
   for each function/variable you need.

   ```
   (declare-function test-fun1 "./test1.el")
   (defvar test-var1)
   ```
2. Another option is to `require` the files only conditionally. Add something like this to file `1`:

   ```
   (defvar test1-is-loading t)
   (unless (and (boundp 'test2-is-loading)
                test2-is-loading)
     (require 'test2))
   ```

   And something like this to file `2`:

   ```
   (defvar test2-is-loading t)
   (unless (and (boundp 'test1-is-loading)
                test1-is-loading)
     (require 'test1))
   ```

Comment: The realistic situation is a package where the main file declares some stuff (variables such as a mode map, executable paths, customize group), requires other files providing a bunch of functions for the package, and assembles it all together (at least into a `-mode` function). The example is a toy example, having it use `test-fun2` would not change the problem at all.

Comment: @T.Verron Yes, I worked on the assumption that your example wasn't completely accurate, and I offered workarounds. Still, I stand by my statement that the package can be better designed. In your realistic example, there's no reason why the file who assembles everything together should also be the one to define variables and groups. Make an extra file which contains these definitions (such as `test-variables`), and this file won't have to require any of the others.

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial answer, your first workaround works fine, but it rather tedious. The second one sounds promising, but it will be a bit more complicated: the statements will need to be wrapped in `eval-when-compile`'s, and the packages will need to set their variable to `nil` at the end of the file (because all the files are compiled in a single session). It also has the benefit of showing me why exactly recursive loading is more complicated to avoid than repeated loading.

Comment: And thanks for the refactoring suggestion, this indeed would work.

Answer (score 4):

Your example is weird:

- You `require` test2 at the *end* of test1, whereas `require` should "always" be at the beginning of a file.
- Your test1 does not call any test2 functions, so it doesn't need test2 to work (hence it `require`s it, unnecessarily), and OTOH your test2 does call test1 functions, so it does need test1, yet it fails to `require` it.

IOW, you have your `require`s backward.

Comment: In a real example, `test1` would of course use the functions defined by `test2`, and the package would only be loaded through `test1` (through autoload). Shouldn't this answer be a comment instead? It is just pointing out that my example is rather poorly chosen, and does not otherwise provide an answer to the question.

Comment: @T.Verron This answer answered the specific case you offered. The fact that it was a poorly chosen example is not his fault. ;-)

Comment: Since both answers address this refactoring point, I must assume that it is a valid point given the question. Yours had the benefit of addressing the general problems, plus the pointers in the comment for my specific case. Is this one really likely to be useful to anybody with a real usecase?

Comment: And with a more short-term view, had it been posted as a comment, I could have editted the question to make it (slightly) more realistic. But it is posted as an answer, so I cannot edit the question without making it a different question (different because a former answer would no longer be applicable). Imo, this answer falls precisely in the realm of comments: asking for clarifications (in this case a confirmation that the minimal example is really representative of the problem) from the asker.

Answer (score 3):

The [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Compiler-Errors.html#Compiler-Errors) suggests adding `declare-function` and `defvar` lines.

The resulting `test2` file is:

```
;;; test2.el ---  

;;; Code:

(declare-function test-fun1 "./test1.el")
(defvar test-var1)

(defun test-fun2 ()
  (let ((test test-var1))
    (test-fun1 test)))

(provide 'test2)
;;; test2.el ends here
```

However, this needs to be done for all functions and all variables defined in "parent" files.